# jquery ui autocomplete stopped working for no reason

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

In a website cms I am using jquery autocomplete. I worked like a charm. But suddenly, after a few weeks, it stopped working. Absolutely no code was changed in this period. I'm using jquery 1.6.2 and jquery ui 1.8.13.
Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    var artists = [<?php getArtists(); ?>];
    $("#artistsearch").autocomplete({
        source: artists,
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#artistsearch").val(ui.item.artistsearch);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) { $("#search").submit(); }
    });
});
```

The array `artists` is a correct array, but too long to post here.
I hope that there is anyone over here that can help me out on this one.

Thanks in advance, Richard

I've got a form with a field `artistsearch`

Edit: Thanks people..

I didn't receive notification mails, so a little late with my response.

The echo is IN the getArtist() function and delivers a nice array. As I stated in my original question the whole thing DID work, but suddenly stopped working, without changing any code. At first I thought that it could be an invalid item in the array, so I hardcoded a simple, 2 items array, and it also didn't work.

Could it be a server issue? I realy am confused with this and I didn't see this behavior in my careere before.

Comment: is it that you missed echo in getArtists()....? and stopped working would mean, it doesnt show suggestions at all or shows errors or..?

Comment: The echo could potentially be in the function call itself. However @Richard Knol a little more information would help.

Comment: please post your getArtists() method.

Comment: @Richard Knol: you could post some sample elements of the `artists` array, so we could debug your code.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter, After it stopped working, I tested it with an original demo arry, from the jquery ui autocomplet example. Nothing happened...

Comment: Can you give the code for the php method, and some sample data contained in this array please ? Also, have a look to your Firebug console, you might see some errors (parse or whatever) and then tell us what you get :)

Comment: @RichardKnol: so the [original jQuery UI Autocomplete Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) doesn't work for you? Then something is really messed up in your code - as pomeh said, you could open a console (`F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+I`), and see if there are any error messages, and extend your question with this info. Or you could post a sample code to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) - this way we could really help you. Without seeing your `artists` array and having other infos about your code we can just keep guessing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

It turned out that some of the array-items where breaking the array.
In the getArtist function I switched the quotes, e.g.:
"'" to '"'

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be the following (assuming that your `getArtists()` function doesn't already `echo`), whenever you're using PHP variables inside JavaScript/JQuery you **have** to echo them :) **OR you can use short tag (thanks diEcho)**:

```
$(function() {
    var artists = [<?php echo getArtists(); ?>];
    $("#artistsearch").autocomplete({
        source: artists,
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#artistsearch").val(ui.item.artistsearch);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) { $("#search").submit(); }
    });
});
```

Comment: or use short tag ( if open)  `var artists = [<?=getArtists()?>];`

Comment: Ah didn't know that :) +1 for that.

Comment: @mattytommo: how do you know the `echo`-ing is not inside the `getArtists()` function? You can't be sure about that. But it's true, it could be a potential source of the problem.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter yeah that was basically an assumption, I'll edit to reflect

Comment: @mattytommo: OK, no problem, I just wanted to remind you about the possibility. :)

Comment: Ah, can you post a snippet of the array then?

Comment: @ mattytommo: After it stopped working, I tested it with an original demo array, from the jquery ui autocomplet example. Nothing happened. and the autocomplete didn't work..

Comment: @RichardKnol Ah okay cool, go ahead and put the tick next to your answer to accept your answer :)

Comment: @ mattytommo, haha no, I answered myself to provide more info. I am new to stackoverflow as an asker... so

Comment: @RichardKnol ahh I see, you should have really edited your question to include the info. I've edited it for you, but you'll need to delete your answer yourself.